# Load testing end to end Solr performance

Tags: solr, load-testing

We want to test the performance of Solr search engine at all tiers. So far i have used 'SolrMeter' to test the performance of Solr core under stress, SOAP UI + Load UI to to test the REST-Full service tier. We are now implementing the User interface tier. Which tool would you recommend to test the performance under stress of solr at this UI tier level? I can think of Selenium/Webdriver but was wondering if there was a dedicated tool for the same.

Comment: How does the input in the UI translate to Solr queries?

Comment: The query term in the UI is the exact query being passed to Solr (We are using DisMax parser). There are some additional calls being made to the database to record stuff at the Application level before the query is sent to Solr. When the JSON response is received object are created according to some business rules before the results are displayed. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: What I've done for Solr performance testing is capturing the queries from a live system and then replaying them at different rates. In your case you also want to test the UI part for which I have no ideas besides Selenium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using jMeter.
First use  [JMeter Proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) to save your test scenario (it records your actions in browser).
Then setup a test plan that would fire the test scenario in a thread group (you have to provide number of users/threads, startup time, load time and unload time) which would be recorded in all Listener elements (graphs, tables, ...) you add to your test.

Don't forget to use [jmeter plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) (invaluable jMeter contrib).

Comment: Great tip for using jmeter plugins! So happy to have found 'Variables from CSV' plugin! Thanks! Do you know if there is a plugin for assertions? I want to check if certain number of results are returned in a response and/or if a string is present in the responses. The current documentation for assertions on the jmeter site is too short to be useful.

Comment: see JMeter's [Bean Shell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler)