# Define a group of requests in order to obtain a total time in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I would like to know if there is anyway to create a group of HTTP requests in order to obtain the total time of a request ?

Let me to explain better when i start a login process several resources are loaded since i don't know how to group this login process i have to make a sum of all this resources in order to obtain the waiting time to finish the login. In one user is easy but since i'm testing 1000 user simultaneous it became impossible.

( i want to create a graphic using the number of user vs time of waiting )

best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) as parent of those requests that you need to group together.

To produce graph I suggest you use [JMeter Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11589290/465710) and their Ultimate Thread Group to better control number of users and to show results use [Composite Graph](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/CompositeGraph) in which you'll show number of users and response time.

If you don't want time component you can use [Response times vs Threads](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads). It'll show you number of users on X and response time on Y axis.