# JMeter - How do you group all requests related to a page to provide cleaner results?

Tags: jmeter

Im new to JMeter and have just created a test plan using the proxy server.

The test plan covers a fairly long user journey on a web app with a lot of pages, images, scripts and css being requested, because of this when I run the test plan and view the results in a listener such as the 'View Results Tree' the sampler list is very long and if I try and use a graph there are so many results its hard to make out individual values.

Is there a way in JMeter where I could group all the requests related to a page under that page and only have to page name display in the listener but still have the ability to drill into an individual page and see the details for each sample?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For this you can use Transaction Controller:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller

Keep **Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample** unchecked.

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with PMD, Transaction controller is exactly what you need.
You can achieve that automatically (while you're saving your test) if you enable `jMeter proxy`'s option `Put each group in a new transaction controller`.

A couple of more details (about jMeter Plugins' listeners I regularly use) here:
[Define a group of requests in order to obtain a total time in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065147/define-a-group-of-requests-in-order-to-obtain-a-total-time-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool **BADBOY** tool to record your test and there you can easily bifurcate/ remove the unwanted content. 
From BADBOY you can directly Export the recorded script to JMeter by simply from

> File menu>>Exort To JMeter

This is what currently we are following and is a bit easy to use.