# JMeter doesn't have an answer from server by JSON RPC over TCP protocol until thread is stopped manually

Tags: json, tcp, jmeter, json-rpc

i test a server, which responds on JSON RPC requests over TCP.
I use JMeter, the latest available version 2.8 r1393162.
My test plan has the TCP sampler with JSON RPC ver 1.0 request `{ "method": "registrate", "params": [1,1], "id": 100}`.
When i start it, JMeter doesn't give me an answer until i stop the thread. Server accepted my  request (see it in his log).
When i stop it, i see an answer in View Result Tree.

Is it a bug in sampler or my test?
Is it a bug in tested server?

Comment: Is that request sampler saved using jmeter proxy or you created it manually?  Are you sure that's what your app sends?

Comment: Manually. I don't know about proxy, that allows recording TCP requests. Does is exist? Know only about HTTP Proxy.

Comment: So what was saved when you tried to save your browser interaction with jMeter proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, jMeter proxy is invaluable when you're preparing your test.

So first use proxy to save your actions in browser (you'll see samplers and other components appearing as you click and you'll know what exactly gets sent).

Here's the complete set of instructions on how to use it: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

One important option to enable is jMeter proxy's `Put each group in a new transaction controller` property. Because one click in a browser often results in multiple requests being sent in the background (e.g. every resource, like page, js, image is a separate get request). With this option jMeter groups all requests of each user action into separate transaction controller. You'll see how much cleaner your test and your listeners (graphs, tables) will look like.

Here are the few additional pointers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12068377/465710

Comment: i don't use HTTP, but JSON RPC over TCP

Comment: OK, you're using JSON RPC, but I assumed you're using HTTP as your transport layer. So you're using TCP socket streams?

Comment: E.g. AFAIK GWT uses HTTP as its transport layer and I successfully tested it with jMeter. You can try to save using proxy and see how jMeter sees it.